# JSX/Photoshop: layer opacity issue

Tags: opacity, photoshop, layer, jsx

Photoshop CS6/JSX. I'm changing the opacity of the selected layer by increasing or reducing it by 10. The problems I'm getting:

When reducing the value by 10 I get this secuence of reductions:

100 - 90 - 80 - 71 - 61 - 51 - 41 - 31 - 22 - 12 - 2

When increasing the results are:

0 - 10 - 20 - 31 - 41 - 51 - 61 - 71 - 82 - 92

The code is something like this:

```
var opc = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity;
desc2.putUnitDouble(cTID('Opct'), cTID('#Prc'), opc - 10.0);

/* or

desc2.putUnitDouble(cTID('Opct'), cTID('#Prc'), opc + 10.0); */
```

Any idea on how to fix it in order to get only multiples of 10?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you just ensure your opc variable is rounded down each to the closest 10 before setting the new value?

Comment: And btw that opacity variable is read/write.  You don't need to deal with that ugly script listener code.

Comment: Well, I was looking for a shortcut that could force the rounded results.I know I can check if the variable is rounded. Also, I know I don´t need the listener. It was generated by the action2js script that it's that ugly. I didn't clean before send it. Please excuse me for that. And many thanks for your help.

Comment: 100-10 = 90.1960784313726 :)

Comment: Math.round() was the shortcut: var opc = Math.round(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity);

Answer (score 1):

Math.round() do the trick. First, force the opacity of the layer to be round:

```
var opc = Math.round(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity)
```

Now you can change the opacity by adding or substracting the desired value:

```
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity = opc -10; //or +10
```

Thanks to Anna Forrest for the help.